# How to set JAVA_HOME in MacOS Monterey when /usr/libexec/java_home returns an error?

Tags: java, macos, java-home, macos-monterey

I recently got this new MacBook Pro (2021) 16" with MacOs Monterey and trying to install Java (openjdk11). I installed Homebrew and used `brew install openjdk@11` to install java. I get following when executed `java --version` command,

```
openjdk 11.0.15 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.15+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.15+0, mixed mode)
```

But when I execute `/usr/libexec/java_home`, I get the following,

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

Which I also had set as my JAVA_HOME after adding `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` to `~/.zshrc`.

Even the folder `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` is empty.

Tried uninstalling according to `www.java.com` and then reinstall using `brew` but still getting the same issue.

[image: Terminal]

Comment: what happens if you type `echo $JAVA_HOME` in the terminal app?

Comment: @blurfus Sorry when executed `/usr/libexec/java_home` I get this error. which led me to reinstall java(updated the question). When $JAVA_HOME is set to  `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`, I get the same error "The operation ...." in the question. Otherwise its empty (when not set).

Comment: Please read my comment again ;) - in the terminal, type: `>echo $JAVA_HOME` - then, let us know the output of the command.

Comment: btw, you don't _execute_ `/usr/libexec/java_home` - that's the location of the JAVA HOME -

Comment: @blurfus its an empty line, when I type `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Odd. if you type `java --version` - do you still get the output above?

Comment: yes, I get that

Comment: yeah we don't execute `/usr/libexec/java_home` what I meant was, when I type it in the terminal I get that error. I am supposed to get the JAVA_HOME from that right? since we set it as our JAVA_HOME? @blurfus

Comment: no, you are not supposed to get the JAVA_HOME from that. That's the value, not a command to retrieve the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245210/discussion-between-blurfus-and-gayal-kuruppu).

Answer (score 8):

On the Homebrew OpenJDK formula page (last check: 19 dec 2022),
[there is this note that says](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk#:%7E:text=For%20the%20system%20Java%20wrappers%20to%20find%20this%20JDK):

> For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
> `sudo ln -sfn $(brew --prefix)/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`

If like me you need the `JAVA_HOME` variable in your shell, you can add this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

(Tested with MacOS Monterey and Ventura update).

Answer (score 1):

Could not solve the Original Problem then used `brew install --cask temurin11` (https://adoptium.net/installation/) and installed Java with no problem.

Comment: So the issue was with the brew installer then?

Comment: I guess so. Even re installing didn’t work.